# iOS: Return 2 count values in numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, xcode, count, tableview

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    int count = [entries count];
    if (count == 0) {
        return kCustomRowCount;
    }

    return count;

    int rowCount;
    if (self.isFiltered) {
        rowCount = filteredTableData.count;

    }
    else {
        rowCount = allTableData.count;
    }

    return rowCount;
}
```

My problem: The first function `return count;` is needed to fill the parsed data into the tableView. The second one `return rowCount;` is needed to count the filtered entries for the search. But when I use both, my App dies. When I delete the first part, the search seems to work incorrectly..

Comment: Are you saying that your viewcontroller is managing more than one tableView?

Comment: No. I just added the second one for my UISearchBar. But I don't know how to combine both..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sascha

It sounds like you need to be making use of the UISearchDisplayController.  This controller essentially supports an unfiltered and a filtered (searched) list.

You can then use something like the following in your numberOfRowsInSection:

```
// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
        // search view population
        return [self.filteredList count];
    } else {
        return [[self.sectionedList objectAtIndex:section] count];
    }
}
```